# Como puedo cargar un svg a mysql mediante PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, codeingiter

Tengo un input file el cual me permite cargar un svg que recibo mediante POST, sin mebargo ese svg lo quiero lamacenar en la base de datos pero no se como enviar los datos para poder almacenarlo.

Comment: Qué intentaste? Qué averiguaste? Cuál fue el resultado? Leete el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y fijate cómo preguntar. Una simple búsqueda en google te daría la respuesta que necesitas.

Comment: consulta, quieres que se vea el código SVG en estructura html completo en tu BD???

Comment: Hola Luis, No es necesario verlo en la bd, sin embargo es necesario que cuando se recupere sea procesado como una imagen.